# Are element-wise operations faster with NumPy functions than operators?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, element

I recently came across a [great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922231/pythons-sum-vs-numpys-numpy-sum) in which a user suggests that `numpy.sum` is faster than Python's `sum` when it comes to dealing with NumPy arrays.

This made me think, are element-wise operations on NumPy arrays faster with NumPy functions than operators? If so, then why is this the case?

Consider the following example.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(1e10)
b = np.random.random(1e10)
```

Will `np.subtract(a, b)` be reliably faster than `a - b`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, not in a significant way.

The reason `np.sum` is faster than `sum` is that `sum` is implemented to "naively" iterate over the iterable (in this case, the numpy array), calling elements' `__add__` operator (which imposes a significant overhead), while numpy's implementation of `sum` is optimized, e.g. taking advantage of the fact it knows the type (dtype) of the elements, and that they are contiguous in memory.

This is not the case with `np.subtract(arr1, arr2)` and `arr1-arr2`. The latter roughly translates to the former.

The difference arises from the fact one can override the subtraction operator in python, so numpy arrays override it to use the optimized version.  The `sum` operation, however, is not overridable, so numpy provides an alternative optimized version of it.

Answer (score 10):

Not really. You can check the timings pretty easily though.

```
a = np.random.normal(size=1000)
b = np.random.normal(size=1000)

%timeit np.subtract(a, b)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 µs per loop

%timeit a - b
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.47 µs per loop

%timeit np.divide(a, b)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.51 µs per loop

%timeit a / b
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.38 µs per loop
```

The numpy functions actually seem to be a tad slower. I'm not sure if that's significant, but I suspect it might be because of some additional function call overhead on top of the same implementation.

EDIT: As @unutbu notes, it's probably because `np.add` and friends have additional type-checking overhead to convert array-likes to arrays when necessary, so stuff like `np.add([1, 2], [3, 4])` works.

Comment: `np.subtract` has extra code to convert its arguments to arrays. Thus `np.subtract([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` works. `a-b` does not need this extra code, so it is a tad faster. `np.subtract` also handles the `out` keyword parameter...

Comment: Good point, @unutbu. Both of those additional features of `np.subtract` are one-time issues at the entry/exit of the function. They are `O(1)` if you are not using them, so they'll become increasingly negligible overhead with larger and larger arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by @shx2.

I will just expand slightly on `sum` vs. `np.sum`:

- built-in `sum` will go through an array, take the elements one-by-one and **convert them each to a Python object** before adding them together as Python objects.
- `np.sum` will sum the array using an optimized loop in native code, without any conversion of the individual values (as shx2 points out, this crucially requires homogeneity and contiguity of the array contents)

The conversion of every array element to a Python object is by far the major source of the overhead.

By the way, this also explains why it is **dumb** to use Python's [standard-library C array type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) for math. `sum(list)` is a *lot faster* than `sum(array.array)`.

Answer (score 1):

`a-b` translates into a function call `a.__rsub__(b)`.  Thus it uses the method that belongs to the variable (e.g. compiled numpy code if `a` is an array).

```
In [20]: a.__rsub__??
Type:       method-wrapper
String Form:<method-wrapper '__rsub__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0xad27a88>
Docstring:  x.__rsub__(y) <==> y-x
```

The doc for `np.subtract(x1, x2[, out])` shows that it is a `ufunc`.  `ufunc` often use the compiled operations like `__rsub__`, but may add a bit of overhead to fit the `ufunc` protocol.

In a number of other cases `np.foo(x, args)` translates to `x.foo(args)`.

In general, if the functions and operators end up calling compiled numpy code to do the actual calculations, the timings will be quite similar, especially for large arrays.