# Speeding up summation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I have a large list with numbers `n1` in `listn1`. I want to add all multiples of each number, if the multiplicand is not in another list `listn2` (prime numbers with specific characteristics) and the product is below a maximum `max_n`. The multiplicand is in most cases below 10, but can go up to 100,000. My code so far looks like:

```
s = 0
for n1 in listn1:
    s += sum(n1 * i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1) if i not in listn2)
```

The problem: this approach is sloooow. It takes seconds to calculate `listn1` and `listn2`, so I know that there are more than a million numbers to add. But I started the summation yesterday evening and it is still running this morning.

Is there a Pythonic way to speed up this summation?

Comment: For starters, make `listn2` a `set`. `if x in y` is an `O(1)` operation on avg if `y` is a set and `O(len(y))` on avg if `y` is a list. Also, try to work with `numpy` so you can vectorize some operations.

Comment: You can use the sum of `arithmetic and geometric sequences` for get sum of n1 * i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1), than get other sum when i in listn2, all this using matlap feature

Comment: @Deepspace: Didn't know that difference between set and list. Will have to keep `setn2` and `listn2`, because `setn2` will lose the order of `listn2`. `numpy` resisted an installation on my computer, but it seems I have to give it another try.

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana True, `listn2` has less elements, so will need less operations. Maybe I should add the elements in `n2` in advance and then just look up the result, so it doesn't have to do this summation every time from scratch. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to the input I just noticed that `n1 * sum(i)` requires way less operations than `sum(n1 * i)`.  Way to go.

Comment: A set will only contain unique values of the list. This will help speed up, if listn2 has repetition of any value. I am not sure, if apart from this, there is any other reason as well, because of which set would be faster.

Comment: @SachitNagpal I tried both, `setn2` and `list(setn2)`. Though both contain the same number of elements, the computation time with `setn2` is massively reduced. Not sure, why, but @Deepspace was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions for you.

**First of all**, you don't have multiply `i` with `n1` at each iteration. You can replace

```
s += sum(n1 * i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1) if i not in listn2)
```

with

```
s += n1 * sum(i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1) if i not in listn2)
```

They are totally same.

**Secondly**, without `if i not in listn2` condition, you have a simple summation:

```
sum(i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1)
```

This is same with `sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., (max_n // n1)])`, and equals `(max_n // n1) * (1 + max_n // n1) / 2`. For a simply example, take a look at [this](https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/).

To handle `if i not in listn2` condition, if your `listn2` is smaller, you can sum `listn2` instead of `listn1`.

**So**, find the sum of `listn1` and subtract the items in `listn2`:

```
def sum_until(l, max):
    return sum([x for x in l if x < max])

listn2 = list(set(listn2))

for n1 in listn1:
    finish = max_n // n1
    s += n1 * (finish * (finish + 1) / 2 - sum_until(listn2, finish))
```

**EDIT:**

I guess NumPy would be faster for sum. Make `listn2` a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

listn2 = np.array(list(set(listn2)))
```

And use this `sum_until` function:

```
def sum_until(listn2, max):
    l = listn2[np.where(listn2 <= max)]
    return int(np.sum(l))
```

Comment: Are we telepathically connected? I wrote your first suggestion in the other comment section, while you were typing it. Thanks, will implement all suggestions.

Comment: :):) You're welcome. Second one is more effective for speeding up if `listn2` is small. If it is not small enough, you can define it as numpy array. Numpy sum is faster.

Comment: I thought now about summing up `listn2` elements in advance in `sumlistn2`, then look up index in `listn2` and retrieve the sum from `sumlistn2`. `setn2` would be faster, I learned now, but it loses the order, I need. Numpy resisted installation, I have to look into this.

Comment: I agree about telepathic connection :):) I was looking for a better way of `listn2` sum. I've used `sorted()` and `np.cumsum()`. I am still trying, there is a mistake in somewhere, and I can't find it.

Comment: Thanks, but please don't put any more effort into it. I rather need algorithmic suggestions than the actual code. Not a programmer here, so program structure is my problem.

Comment: OK, I put everything I have to my answer, and made a correction in the code. I hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestions on board, I re-wrote the code to

```
setn2 = set(listn2)
s = 0
for n1 in listn1:
    s += n1 * (max_n * (max_n + 1) // 2 - sum(i for i in range(1, 1 + max_n // n1) if i in setn2))
```

Instead of hours, the summation now takes seconds.

**Several hours later**

Coming across this old question of mine, it turned out that retrospectively, I did the right thing. The idea mentioned here in this thread to use `numpy.sum()` instead was well intended but wrong, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908528/8881141). If you work in numpy, fine, but if you have a Python list, use comprehensions.