# Why am I getting this MemoryError?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I ran into a strange `MemoryError`, and I don't understand why it's there. Code example:

```
# some setup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

blah = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000,2)), columns=['foo','bar'])
blah['cat'] = blah.apply(lambda x: random.choice(['A','B']), axis=1)
blah['bat'] = blah.apply(lambda x: random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5]), axis=1)

# the relevant part:
blah['test'] = np.where(blah.cat == 'A',
    blah[['bat','foo']].groupby('bat').transform(sum),
    0)
```

Assigning `blah['test']` in this way crashes with a `MemoryError`, *but*: if I instead do this:

```
blah['temp'] = blah[['bat','foo']].groupby('bat').transform(sum)
blah['test'] = np.where(blah.cat == 'A',
    blah['temp'],
    0)
```

everything works fine. My guess is that there's something about how `np.where` and `.groupby()` interact that causes this.

However, if my initial `blah` only has columns `'foo', 'cat', 'bat'` (so no column `bar` that isn't directly involved in the failing section of code) everything is also fine with the first way of doing it, so that just confuses me more.

What's going on here?

Comment: Side note / possibly relevant: use `'sum'` intead of `sum`, you should avoid using Python built-ins with Pandas / NumPy objects.

Comment: But why, @jpp? Isn't it less overhead when built-ins are used?

Comment: @ayorgo, Not in the case of NumPy: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922231/pythons-sum-vs-numpys-numpy-sum).

Comment: @jpp Yes, "avoid using Python builtins" is certainly true here, but I believe that passing `sum` maps to the NumPy ufunc.  See `pandas.core.base.SelectionMixin`; `SelectionMixin._builtin_table.get(sum, sum)`

Comment: @BradSolomon, Nice, didn't know that! Though I think it's good practice to use strings in the *general case*. That mapping seems to be an implementation detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first portion of your code is simply not correct. If you reduce the dataframe size you'll get

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1000, placement implies 1
```

which suggests that `np.where` fails to iterate over the single-column dataframe returned by

```
blah[['bat','foo']].groupby('bat').transform(sum)
```

and tries to put the entire column to each element of `blah['test']` presumably allocating memory for the whole operation in advance which causes the `MemoryError`.

Changing your implementation to

```
blah['test'] = np.where(blah.cat == 'A',
                        blah[['bat','foo']].groupby('bat')['foo'].transform(sum),
                        0)
```

should help.

Comment: @jezrael I figured restricting variables first would use slightly less memory (does it?), which is relevant for my actual use-case. Anyhow, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
blah['test'] = np.where(blah['cat'] == 'A',
    blah[['bat','foo']].groupby('bat')['bat'].transform(sum),
    0)
```

Notice that I added a `['bat']` at the end of `groupby('bat')`.

My rationale is that your python is hitting MemoryError because it is trying to `sum` everything in your Dataframe since it isn't defined specifically what you wanted to `sum`

Comment: My understanding was that it applies the functions in the `.transform()` to whatever in the dataframe isn't in the list of `.groupby()` variables, so when I say `blah[['bat', 'foo']]` it sums `foo` for each `bat` group, which is what I want. In any case, how does this explain the difference in behaviour?

Comment: @KetilTveiten You're not specifying what you wish to `sum`. You're just specifying which columns you wish to keep in `blah[['bat', 'foo']]` and which column you wish to groupby in `.groupby('bat')`

Comment: Ok, but the groupby/sum works fine when not inside the `np.where`, this is where the confusion arises.

Comment: @KetilTveiten It is not working fine. You will notice you are putting the entire dataframe into your existing dataframe and the values will be incorrect