# Adding values from a system of equations

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, -0.15],[-0.1,1]])
b = np.array([10000, 18000])
print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
```

It gives me these value outputs which are correct:

```
[12893.40101523 19289.34010152]
```

I need a code that will add these two values together.

Comment: np.sum(np.linalg.solve(a,b))

Answer (score 3):

Use the following program to compute the sum:

```
print(sum(np.linalg.solve(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.sum` [which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10922744/2400117) for `numpy` arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, -0.15],[-0.1,1]])
b = np.array([10000, 18000])
print(np.linalg.solve(a,b).sum())
```

Output: `32182.7411168`