# Bugs of Python "num" or "np.sum"?

Tags: python, debugging

I am working on the following code snippets to compute the similarity of two images:

```
import cv2, sys                                                                          [5/981]
import numpy as np

def compute_hisgram(path):
    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    im = cv2.imread(path)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    h = hog.compute(im)

    return h

def histogram_intersection(h1, h2):
    # minima = np.minimum(h1, h2)
    # intersection = np.true_divide(np.sum(minima), np.sum(h2))
    #return intersection
    return cv2.compareHist(h1, h2, cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT)


h1 = compute_hisgram(sys.argv[1])
h2 = compute_hisgram(sys.argv[2])

h12 = histogram_intersection(h1, h2)


# to normalize, we need to divide by the original image.
print (h12/np.sum(h2))
```

And when executing the above code with two images as the input, it outputs a value that is close to 1.0, which seems quite normal.

```
python3 t.py image1.png image2.png
0.9932124283243112
```

However, to my very much surprise, when the last statement is written in the following way:

```
print (h12/sum(h2))
```

**The output is different, and it is a number larger than 1**! And the code is just much slower than before.

```
python3 t.py image1.png image2.png
[1.1126189]
```

Is it a bug of Python `sum` function? Or am I missed anything here? Thanks.

======== update

Here is the output of `print (h2)`:

```
[[0.0924307 ]
 [0.05680538]
 [0.07150667]
 ...
 [0.10983132]
 [0.17328948]
 [0.0688285 ]]
```

And `h12`:

```
4517725.058263534
```

Comment: Can you show me the output of `print(h2)`?

Comment: It's purely on the datatype

Comment: @lllllllllllll How about `h12`?

Comment: How about `sum` and `np.sum` of `h2`? I can explain the speed difference but not the value difference.

Comment: You can get the explanation of performance from https://stackoverflow.com/q/10922231/4050015. But the value should not differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions do the summing differently.
Example:

```
a = np.full((9000,), 1/9000)
sum(a)
# 0.9999999999998027
np.sum(a)
# 0.9999999999999999
math.fsum(a)
# 1.0
```

So np.sum() gives the more accurate result than sum().

See [fsum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) for some explanations:

> math.fsum(iterable)
>
> Return an accurate floating point sum of values in the iterable. Avoids loss of precision by tracking multiple intermediate partial
>     The algorithm’s accuracy depends on IEEE-754 arithmetic guarantees and the typical case where the rounding mode is half-even. On some
>   non-Windows builds, the underlying C library uses extended precision
>   addition and may occasionally double-round an intermediate sum causing
>   it to be off in its least significant bit.
>
> For further discussion and two alternative approaches, see the ASPN cookbook recipes for accurate floating point summation.

You may also want to have a look at [accupy](https://github.com/nschloe/accupy). There are some very informative charts on accuracy of different summation methods.

The following is a really pathological example (take from [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2448)), obviously the accurate result is exactly 20000:

```
a = [1, 1e100, 1, -1e100] * 10000
math.fsum(a), np.sum(a), sum(a)
# (20000.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```