# How to find the difference of images in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 images.  I'm expecting an integer as my result, but I'm not getting what I expect.

```
from imageio import imread
#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glennford49/sampleImages/main/cat1.png
#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glennford49/sampleImages/main/cat2.png
img1="cat1.png" # 183X276
img2="cat2.png" # 183x276
numpyImg1=[]
numpyImg2=[]
img1=imread(img1)
img2=imread(img2)
numpyImg1.append(img1)
numpyImg2.append(img2)
diff = numpyImg1[0] - numpyImg2[0] 
result = sum(abs(diff)) 

print("difference:",result)
```

print:

```
# it prints an array of images rather than printing an interger only
```

target:

```
difference: <int>
```

Comment: Difference in images could mean a lot of things. The image data you are loading using `imread` will be a ndarray with shape (height, width, channels). So if you have 3 RGB values for each pixel of the image, how do you want to define difference?

Comment: Now , I've seen this. Looks like it can give an integer result  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my answer of finding the difference of 2 images in rgb channels.

If 2 the same images were to be subtracted,
prints:
difference per pixel: 0

```
from numpy import sum
from imageio import imread

#https://github.com/glennford49/sampleImages/blob/main/cat2.png
#https://github.com/glennford49/sampleImages/blob/main/cat2.png
img1="cat1.png"
img2="cat2.png"
numpyImg1=[]
numpyImg2=[]
img1=imread(img1)
img2=imread(img2)
numpyImg1.append(img1)
numpyImg2.append(img2)
diff = numpyImg1[0] - numpyImg2[0] 
result = sum(diff/numpyImg1[0].size)
result = sum(abs(result.reshape(-1))) 
print("difference per pixel:",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python's built-in `sum` function which only performs a summation [along the first dimension of a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666553/3250829).  This is the reason why you are getting a 2D array as the output instead of the single integer you expect.  Please use [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) on your result instead which will internally flatten a multi-dimensional NumPy array then sum over the results.  In addition, you might as well use [`numpy.abs`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) for the absolute computation too:

```
import numpy as np

result = np.sum(np.abs(diff))
```

Using `numpy.sum` means that you no longer need to reshape your array into a flattened representation prior to using the built-in `sum` function in your answer.  For future development, **always** use NumPy methods on any arithmetic operations you want to perform on NumPy arrays.  It prevents unexpected behaviour such as what you've just seen.

Answer (score -1):

A (Colored) image is a 3D matrix, so what you can do is convert those image in `numpy` array using `numpy.array(image)` and then you can get the difference of those two `numpy` arrays.

The final answer will be an array in 3-dimenssion

Comment: deviding the result with numpyImg1[0].size gives the array of 2-dimension

Comment: okay so if you got the 2d array then just subtract those, you will get a 2d array as an answer, its basic matrix arithmetics

Comment: what kind of subtraction you are trying to do is still confusing

Answer (score -1):

I believe the dimension of numpy array is not 1, You need to perform the sum the number of times as the dimesion of the array to have a single sum value.

```
   [1,2,3]
    sum gives : 6

   [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
   sum gives : [2,4,6]
   doing a second sum opertion gives
     : 12 (single value)
```

you may need to add one more "sum(result)" before printing data (if image is 2 dimension) .

eg:

```
     numpyImg2.append(img2)
     diff = numpyImg1[0] - numpyImg2[0] 
     result = sum(abs(diff)) 

     result = sum(result) >> Repeat

     print("difference:",result)
```

Comment: this is the result : difference: [191  14  25]  ,almost near to my expected output

Comment: We can use reshape on numpy array to flatten it using -1 shape input. Please try the same.     numpyImg2.append(img2)
     diff = numpyImg1[0] - numpyImg2[0] 
     result = sum(abs(diff.reshape(-1)))
     print("difference:",result)

Comment: It now gives me a number of several digits, but the answer should be not less than 20 or so because image1 and image2 are the same cat , only the background color is the difference

Comment: Looks  like it can give me an integer result, the arguments arr for normalize confuses me, any exxplaination on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images